# UIButton setTitleColor and setImage not working

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am using the StoryBoard feature for my iPhone project. In the storyboard, I have a view controller with a table view using prototype cells. Inside the prototype cell, I have a UIButton (rounded rectangle) hooked up to a sub-classed UIButton class. The tableview gets its data from an array, and the data is printed out in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, I conditionally modify the cell's appearance. This is when I start getting problems. I am able to successfully change the text of the button. However, if I attempt to change the image of the button, using:

```
[cell.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mynewimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the image is changed, but the text disappears.

If I attempt to change the text color of the button, using:

```
[cell.myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.77] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Nothing happens whatsoever. The color remains the same (unless I also try to change the image, in which case it completely disappears).

I am sensing I am doing something fundamentally wrong here -- do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

to change image with text left

use

```
btn.titleLabel.textColor = yourcolor;
```

to change text color

Comment: Great, the image is set correctly now (the text doesn't disappear). However, nothing happens with the text color...

Answer (score 4):

Define myButton as below and check.This may be the wrong in your code.The code is:

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

This is newly editted part:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:yourimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setTitleColor:yourcolor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: The button is not programmatically added -- it is added in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to set  different properties to a  Custom Button...You also find that  setBackgroudimage and setTitleColor properties here...

```
    UIButtin  *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(165, 205, 65, 40)];
   [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.77]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [myButton setTitle:@"Hi....." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mynewimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [cell  addSubview:myButton];
```

Thank u..

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to change your button background:

```
[cell.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mynewimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text disappears because you have set the image at button front side as button main image.

```
[cell.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mynewimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You need to set the button background image so that your text would be visible as the image will be drawn at the rear side of your UIButton context.

So just replace the above line of code to :

```
[cell.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mynewimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```